# Is it possible to search a spreadsheet for criteria from a list

Tags: excel

I am wondering is it possible to search a spreadsheet for criteria from a list?

**Example:**

Formulas!B6 contains Red, search Laptops!D2 for Red, return string Red to Formulas!E1

Formulas!B7 contains Orange, search Laptops!D2 for Orange, return string Orange to Formulas!E1

**What I have tried**

=LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH(B$6:B$21,Laptops!D2),E1)

Am I going in the right direction with the Lookup function?

**Laptops Sheet**

[image]

**Formulas Sheet**

[image]

Comment: If I understand the input correctly, you need something very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484287/excel-print-values-from-column-a-not-found-in-column-b-in-column-c/ However, try to modify your request using more general description, e.g. "I need to lookup list of PC configs for another list of color values", because now I understand that you need to put every time each lookup to the SAME cell E1, and this is impossible using formulas. In other case I think the solution is pretty simple and similar to the above link.

Comment: Thank you for the link however I was not able to get that to work for me. I have had some success with a different formula =IFERROR(LEFT(Laptops!A2,AGGREGATE(15,6,SEARCH(Formulas!A$2:A$8,Laptops!A2),1)-1),"")

Comment: Ok got a working formula. =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND($A$2:$A$8,Laptops!A2)),-1,1)*(ROW($A2:$A8)-ROW(A2)+1))),"Color Not Present")  cell references from the pics can be easily applied to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got a working formula. =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND($A$2:$A$8,Laptops!A2)),-1,1)*(ROW($‌​A2:$A8)-ROW(A2)+1))),"Color Not Present") cell references from the pics can be easily applied to this

Comment: And with Error checking =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND($A$2:$A$8&" ",Laptops!A2&" ")),-1,1)*(ROW($A2:$A8)-ROW(A2)+1))),"Color Not Present")